# How to make Combo Box using WinForms and C#

Tags: c#, combobox

I am new to `WinForms` coding and I am trying to make this minipaint which has 3 buttons (`circle`, `line` and `rectangle`). Here are my buttons:

```
private void circle_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    circle c = new circle() {startx=10,thickness=4,starty=10,radius=100,color=Color.Black };
    shapes.Add(c);
    panel1.Invalidate();
}
private void rectangle_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rectangle r = new rectangle() { startx = 10,thickness=4, starty = 10, length = 200, width = 100, color = Color.Black };
    shapes.Add(r);
    panel1.Invalidate();
}

private void line_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    line l = new line() {startx=10,starty=10,thickness=4,endx=200,endy=200,color=Color.Black };
    shapes.Add(l);
    panel1.Invalidate();
}
```

When I click on them, a random shape will be printed on my `Panel`. I want to make a `ComboBox` , which has these three values(circle, line and rectangle) which lets me choose one of them in order to change it's properties in a `PropertyGrid`. I tried something like:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button namestr = line_btn;
    comboBox1.Items.Add(namestr);
}
```

but I know it is not right. How am I suppose to do that?

Comment: What is going wrong? Is there a failure when the SelectedIndex is changed, or is one of the other buttons not functioning?

Comment: the buttons are functioning correctly but my combobox is still empty

Comment: If you haven't added anything to your combobox, how can the SelectedIndex change? You need to add something to it first, then change the index to enter the SelectedIndexChanged event handler.

Comment: Question title: "how to make combobox c#" ... Comment: "but my combobox is still empty" ... please re-read your question (do not fill in the empty gaps) and edit it, so we can at least understand what you are actually asking.

Comment: that means I tried to make a combobox but it's not functioning properly. I think this is pretty clear

Comment: What you have shown is that nothing is in the box, so that means you can't change the index. If this isn't the issue, then you haven't asked a complete question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you could do is to populate your `ComboBox` first eg. in the constructor:

```
public Form1()
{
   comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new List<string>() { "circle", "line", "rectangle"}.ToArray());
}
```

or you take already an array:

```
public Form1()
{
   comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new string []{ "circle", "line", "rectangle"});
}
```

and switch according to the values in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
    {
        case "circle":
            //do something circular
            break;
        case "line":
            //do something linish
            break;
        case "rectangle":
            //do something edgy
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for answering my question but the line "comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new List<string>() { "circle", "line", "rectangle"});" has some errors

Comment: sorry forgot a decisive element at the end: `.ToArray()`. The method needs an array not a list. I edited my post. You can already take the `string[]`